# How to communicator between two fragment using scrollView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm making android app using ScrollView fragment. Like picture below[image]

In first fragment i have a radio button. I want when I choose that radio button, the second 2 will display "Radio Button 1 was Chosen" in textView. Picture Fragment 2 Below:
[image]

My trying:

**Fragment 1 java code:**

```
public class iq_hard_2 extends Fragment{

    RadioButton r1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer_2_iq_hard, container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        r1 =(RadioButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.r1_hard);
        if(r1.isChecked())
        {

            ((Communicator)getActivity()).respond("RadioButton 1 was Chosen "  );
        }
    }   
}
```

**Fragment 2 java code:**

```
public class iq_hard_3 extends Fragment {
        static TextView textpoint;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer_3_iq_hard, container,false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            textpoint = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.point);
        }
        public static void updateData(String data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textpoint.setText(data);
        }
    }
```

**Main_Fragment Java Code**

```
    public class iq_hard_1 extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator {

    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layer_1_iq_hard_main);
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));
    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            CharSequence title = null;
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                title ="Question 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                title ="Question 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                title ="Question 3";
                break;
            case 3:
                title ="Question 4";
                break;
            }
            return title;
        }
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                fragment = new iq_hard_2();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new iq_hard_3();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new iq_hard_4();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new iq_hard_5();
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 4;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        iq_hard_3.updateData(data);
    }

}
```

**Communicator Java Code**

```
public interface Communicator {
public void respond(String data);
}
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use child fragments as you are using a `ViewPager`, so you have to build three fragments, base fragment that contain nothing but a place holder, the second fragment is your fragment 1 and the third fragment is your fragment 2.
Now when creating the base fragment add an instance to fragment 1 inside the place holder using 'getChildFragmentManager' and adding a transaction, now on the event of the radio button begin a new transaction using 'getChildFragmentManager' and replace fragment 1 with fragment 2, then pass the data to the second fragment using setArgument and a bundle.

Thats it.

EDIT: 
To clarify it this is the steps:

1. Create a fragment named BaseFragment.
2. Create a layout file for this fragment containing nothing but a FrameLayout the match parent.
3. Create your first fragment class and layout as in your question.
4. Create your second fragment class and layout as in your question.
   in the base fragment class in `onCreateView` method: create an instance of first fragment and add it in the FragmentLayout placeholder, this can be done using Fragment transaction and `getChildFragmentManager' method.
5. In your first fragment class add an event to your RadioButton, in the event you can create and instance of the second fragment pass the data to it using setArgument and replace the current fragment with it using `getFragmentManager` and 'replace' method of 'FragmentTransaction'
6. in your 'onCreateView' of the second fragment get the argument and view it.
7. Now don't add the first fragment to the pager, just add the base fragment.

Comment: Still dont understand :( please give me demo

Comment: I've added some steps

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/category/view-pager/
just you go through it and download the source code from there and you can understand it very easily

Answer (score 0):

this is my suggestion:

1. create an event using an interface in Fragment 1
2. implement the interface by the Activity add the unImplemented method of the interface.
3. on onAttach() method of the fragment register the listener of the activity.
4. when the user press your button send an event to the activity via the method of the interface.
5. call a public method of Fragment 2 from the activity that passes a parameter with your info.

this is Fragement1:

```
    package com.example.tester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;



public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    private OnRadioButtonChecked radioBtnListent;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        radioBtnListent=(OnRadioButtonChecked)activity;//this is the registration 
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    public interface OnRadioButtonChecked
    {
        public String radioBtnChecked(String yourInfo);
    }

}
```

this is Fragment 2 :

```
 package com.example.tester;

import android.app.Fragment;



public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    public void reciveTextFromActivity(String info)
    {
        //set your TextView here
    }
}
```

this is the Activity that hosts the two Fragments:

```
    package com.example.tester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class HostActivity extends Activity implements Fragment1.OnRadioButtonChecked {

    Fragment2 fragment2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragment2=new Fragment2();
    }

    @Override
    public String radioBtnChecked(String yourInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fragment2.reciveTextFromActivity(yourInfo);
        return null;
    }



}
```